# How should I choose the right buck converter IC?

Tags: dc-dc-converter, buck, component-selection, step-down

I'm planning on designing a buck converter for my PCB. The input voltage will be 12-24V and the desired output voltage is 3.3V and around 1A max.

How should I choose the right buck converter IC?

Comment: This stackexchange doesn't recommend specific products - however, "how do I choose" questions are perfectly fair.  You may wish to _edit your question_ to reflect that.

Comment: You need to make some decisions about cost, board area, maximum ripple at the output, efficiency (heat) and transient response.  These are the primary factors in designing a buck converter.  Once you have identified the parameters that are critical to your application, you will get better guidance on selecting a converter.  As is, the question is awfully broad.

Answer (score 0):

Like TimWescott said, we can't recommend a specific product for you but the process is very simple: First you need to define any other constraints that you may have - switching frequency, temperature rise, space claim, etc. Past that, go to a site like Digikey or Mouser and look for buck converters, filtering by the criteria you have. Then just choose one! As long as you have correctly defined your constraints and designed your circuit, there won't be any real wrong answers.

Comment: There *are* some more considerations than this though--I would in particular note that for ease of use, you *probably* want a current-mode controller, and that a synchronous converter is usually better than a non-synchronous one. And make sure you find a suitable inductor, too--you might start out designing and then find that your inductor needs to be enormous, and that might make you decide to change to a higher-switching-frequency converter, for instance.